# GWT GoogleAnalytics _trackEvent doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-analytics, dom-events

I followed the instructions here http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GoogleAnalytics, and was able to get the GoogleAnalytics injected but I have a few issues:

They say you don't have to call `init(userAccount)` because gin does it for you, I found that this is not true and I have to call `init()` by myself, which I fear is not the best practice.

I tried calling `trackEvent` with the necessary arguments but nothing happened. I'm using Chrome; I can see the scripts have been loaded to the page and tried to track the network for any outgoing calls, and nothing is sent from my browser.

I tried using the JSNI calls, writing the Javascript by myself in GWT but that gave no different result at all.

Any help whatsoever would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've relied on JSNI with Google Analytics and it works for me, because I can see events in my Analytics control panel. Are you sure you've placed correct initialization in your html file? I'm not familiar with that gwt-platform library which you use, maybe it's outdated?

Here are my tracking methods:

```
    private static native void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label) /*-{
        $wnd._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, label]);
    }-*/;

    private static native void trackEvent(String category, String action, String label, int intArg) /*-{
        $wnd._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action, label, intArg]);
    }-*/;

    private static native void trackPageview(String url) /*-{
        $wnd._gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);
    }-*/;
```

And don't forget about this initialization in your module html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-29066117-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!

GoogleAnalytics is a GWT class made for these purposes so you won't need to write all the javascript calls by yourself, it looks almost identical.

I've seen this solution around the forums, I used it and it worked in a regular GWT application, but tried in my GWTP (the one with MVP) application and didn't get any results, I can see the page loading the script and all, but nothing is being sent. I've used JSNI before and have had fine results, but this is just strange..

Any experience with GWTP vs. regular GWT in these cases regarding JSNI?